# Fortran DLL error when using a multivariable function

Tags: dll, fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am currently developping a fortran DLL and I have a problem about multi-variable functions. My final objective are to

- call the DLL functions from VBA
- debug the DLL using a fortran code calling the DLL functions

Here is my simplified case:

**1. Fortran DLL code**

```
module mod_thermo

    implicit none

contains

    function y1(x1) result(y) bind(c, name = "Y1")
        use iso_c_binding, only : c_double
        !GCC$ attributes dllexport, stdcall :: y1
        real(c_double) :: x1
        real(c_double) :: y

        y = 2.d0 * x1

    end function

    function y2(x1, x2) result(y) bind(c, name = "Y2")
        use iso_c_binding, only : c_double
        !GCC$ attributes dllexport, stdcall :: y2
        real(c_double) :: x1
        real(c_double) :: x2
        real(c_double) :: y

        y = 2.d0 * x1 * x2

    end function

end module
```

**2. Fortran DLL compilation options with GCC**

Compiler is GCC. Compilations options are:

- -static (to avoid dependencies to other dll)
- -Wl,--kill-at (VBA related)
- -fno-underscoring (VBA related)

Output files are located in the project folder of the fortran code for future debug:

- dll_thermo.dll
- libdll_thermo.a
- libdll_thermo.def

**3. Fortran code for DLL testing (interfaces + program)**

The DLL is linked to the code by liking library **libdll_thermo.a**

```
module mod_thermo

    implicit none

    interface

        function y1(x1) result(y) bind(c,name="Y1")
            use iso_c_binding, only : c_double
            real(c_double) :: x1
            real(c_double) :: y
        end function

        function y2(x1, x2) result(y) bind(c,name="Y2")
            use iso_c_binding, only : c_double
            real(c_double) :: x1
            real(c_double) :: x2
            real(c_double) :: y
        end function
    end interface

end module

program main

    use mod_thermo
    implicit none

    write(*,*)"y1 calls:"
    write(*,*)y1(1.d0) ! output ok
    write(*,*)y1(2.d0) ! output ok
    write(*,*)y1(3.d0) ! output ok

    write(*,*)"y2 calls:"
    write(*,*)y2(1.d0, 1.d0) ! output ok
    write(*,*)y2(2.d0, 2.d0) ! output fails
    write(*,*)y2(3.d0, 2.d0)

end program
```

**4. Output and conclusion**

[image: Fail when performing Y2 second call]

My conclusion is that I do not perform the multivariable DLL function y2 call in a correct way. What would be your way to perform such calls ?

Comment: I think you want `real(c_double), value :: x1` and for the rest of the arguments the same. Otherwise, they are passed as pointers, and you want values. This corrupts the stack, and the second function call fails.

Comment: @ja72 I added the `value` for `x1` and `x2` in both the DLL code and fortran debug code and now I have an error at first y2 call.

Comment: @ja72 I don't see why you think value is required. The code is just invoking regular Fortran functions in the module, Bind(C) doesn't mean the Functions are in C. Or does "!GCC$ attributes dllexport, stdcall" mean effectively this is not Fortran any more as normal argument passing methods have been thrown away?

Comment: Try reversing the order where functions are called. See if the error occurs in `y2(x1,x2)` or still in the second function call `y1(x1)`. This will hint at stack corruption due to  a calling convention mismatch.

Comment: @ja72 As you proposed, I reversed y1 and y2 calls. Now I perform three y2 calls followed by three y1 calls. I did not add any `value` in the variable declaration. Result is that the **third** y2 call leads to a segmentation fault. Compared to original error message, `#3 0x75cda88f` is replaced by `#3 0x75b1a88f`.

Comment: Ok now try removing `stdcall` from the export declatation. I think Fortran expects `stdref` for calling convention.

Comment: Based on this [reference](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/calling+Fortran+routines+in+a+DLL), I believe that `stdcall` is the correct way to do the call. Moreover, using `stdcall` does not cause any problem in VBA. The only problem is the Fortran - Fortran communication.

Comment: [this post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler/topic/585094) supports your claim, although they do include `use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` also. But the TCL reference you posted omits the `stdcall` keyword.

Comment: I really do not like that `module mod_thermo` is declared twice. Modules are not like namespaces where the code can span multiple files. The entire `interface` block in the program is superfluous since the functions are declared inside a module anyway. I mean you don't need interfaces when calling other functions declared in modules and imported using the `use` clause, like `use iso_fortran_env`.

Comment: I changed the DLL testing code (see question edit) and now the compiler complains that it cannot find file 'mod_thermo.mod'. I do not understand why this file is required as I expected the dll to embed all the necessary dependencies. 
I guess the link to the DLL is not ok. I added 'libdll_thermo.a' to the link library of the project but this seems not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the link to "libdll_thermo.a". Following tutorial from [here](https://www.fortran.com/Fortran_Tools.pdf), I found out that I should have linked "libdll_thermo.dll". Now it works.